# Grep only Variable Names in Bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed, grep

I have a bash script A, I am writing another script B which prints the variable names which are exported in script A.

Example:

```
export A=TRUE  
  export ABC="GFT"  
export XYZ="FFF"  
\# export P="SSD"
```

If I execute the script A, it has to give output as follows:

```
A  
ABC  
XYZ
```

I have tried this oneline:

```
grep export file.env | grep -v "#" | cut -d' ' -f2 | cut -d'=' -f1
```

But the problem is, if the export is not start from beginning of the line i.e. if there is some space/Tab in the beginning, the above online doesn't work.

Any alternate Solution for this ?

Comment: I think the third line in your desired output should be `XYZ` not `FFF`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk '$1 == "export" { split($2, a, "="); print a[1]; }'
```

Answer (score 2):

A solution using grep:

`grep --perl-regexp --only-matching '\s*export\s+([A-Za-z0-9_]+)='`

Answer (score 1):

`b.sh`:

```
printenv > TMP 
. ./a.sh
printenv | diff TMP - | grep -v printenv | sed -n 's/> *\([^ =]*\)=.*/\1/p'
```

Or to get the changes:

```
set > TMP
. ./a.sh
set | grep -vf - TMP | cut -d= -f1
```

this might give you some extra variables that change such as `BASH_LINENO`.

Comment: This is nice :). This is what I wanted to do. How can I diff to get only changed variables in a.sh (not which are added newly in a.sh)

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -n '/^[[:blank:]]*export[[:blank:]]*\([^=]\{1,\}\)=.*/ s//\1/p' ScriptA
```

`[[:blank:]]` could be replaced by a simple *space* in most of the case